# How to enter window after ledge assassination?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

While I was playing the game I had to perform a ledge assassination on a guard standing by a window.

So I went from below the window and I performed the move well. But i noticed that right after the ledge assassination I can't climb up in any way. Straight up is blocked by some invisible wall and I can't climb the window.

How can I enter a window right after a ledge assassination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is a bug currently present in the game.

I've experienced it myself many times and yes you can't climb up on windows after a ledge assassination.

> The only way for you to climb up is to strafe right or left or down
>   and the "invisible wall" will disappear and you will be able to climb
>   up again to the window and enter the desired buidling.

But entering the window (by climbing up) right after the Ledge Assassination can't be done. Ubisoft may solve it in an upcoming patch.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest patch you can hold L2 (PS3/4) or LT (xBox360/One) to enter a window from any location around the frame.

Comment: This did it for me. In the last mission to kill Germain there is even a prompt tip telling you to use L2 when trying to climb through a window lol.